# How to restart snmpd on Opensolaris after changing snmpd.conf?

Tags: snmp, opensolaris, snmpd

I need to restart snmpd after updating /etc/snmp/conf/snmpd.conf, so it recognizes the changes.  I'm using Net-SNMP 5.4.2 on Opensolaris 10.  I've tried these two:

```
snmpd restart
kill -9 pid
```

The kill command kills it and it fires back up under a new pid, but the new snmpd.conf changes do not seem to be recognized.  I'm adding "disk /" to snmpd.conf, and testing to see what filesystems are mounted by:

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.2
```

But this shows nothing, so I'm under the impression my addition of disk / is not taking.  Am I restarting snmpd correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This restarts snmpd:

```
svcadm restart net-snmp
```

By looking at

```
svcs -a | grep snmp
```

I realized the service is named net-snmp and not snmp, snmpd, or snmpdx.  Opensolaris and snmp are both new to me.

Answer (score 0):

kill -9 kills the process.  have you tried kill -HUP?

From the docs:

The Net-SNMP agent can be instructed to re-read the various configuration files, either via an snmpset assignment of integer(1) to UCD-SNMP-MIB::versionUpdateConfig.0 (.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.100.11.0), or by sending a kill -HUP signal to the agent process.

Comment: I've tried kill -HUP on the snmpd pid, but the process still stays running, and with the same pid.

Answer (score 0):

Does Net-SNMP use the SMF?

If so, I would manage it with `svcadm`.

For example

```
svcadm disable snmpd
svcadm enable snmpd
```

Comment: I'm able to do svcadm disable snmp, but the process still runs for /usr/sbin/snmpd, so that doesn't seem to work either.  Thanks though.

Comment: My hint was nice, but the service name was another one: you found the correct solution. Great!